# Problems finding elements on IE webpage (SAP) to use for Selenium Automation

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, attributes, element

I am trying to automate test cases that are for a SAP CRM application.  On the login page, I can right click to get the element attributes, but once I am logged in, inspect element is not given when right clicking.   I am looking for id or xpath for the elements.  Is there any easy tool I can use for IE explorer to get these?

Things I have tried:

1. Using Selenium IDE in Firefox to record and get elements.  However the SAP webpage does not work in Firefox.
2. I have tried using bookmarklets with internet explorer to get element xpath.  I got errors with this.  I also tried MRI and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In IE hit F12 to open the developer toolbar.  The DOM Explorer is there and then you can use the 'select element' tool that is a pointer on a blank rectangle (ctrl+B).  You should be able to then click on the element on the screen and it focus you there on the HTML.  If there are errors in the browser it may show here even if it renders correctly which might be preventing you from utilizing the selection method and inspect element.  You can manually navigate through the HTML to find what you are looking for in order to identify it.

Also you can use the document.evaluate functionality within dev tools that allows xquery. see reference: [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.evaluate) It is referencing firefox, but I believe that IE11 is enabled to support it.